# Find which two values in an array maximize a given expression?

Tags: c++, algorithm

I met a very simple interview question, but my solution is incorrect. Any helps on this? 1)any bugs in my solution? 2)any good idea for time complexity O(n)?

#### Question:

Given an int array `A[]`, define `X=A[i]+A[j]+(j-i), j>=i`. Find max value of `X`?

#### My solution is:

```
int solution(vector<int> &A){
    if(A.empty())
        return -1;
    long long max_dis=-2000000000, cur_dis;
    int size = A.size();
    for(int i=0;i<size;i++){
        for(int j=i;j<size;j++){
            cur_dis=A[j]+A[i]+(j-i);
            if(cur_dis > max_dis)
                max_dis=cur_dis;
        }
    }
    return max_dis;
}
```

Comment: What if the maximum value of `X` is below `-2000000000`?

Comment: Just an idea (not tested): what about iterating the array from both ends, trying to find the highest number, while decreasing it by the distance from the appripriate end. Would that find the correct indexes (and thus the correct X)?

Comment: Code is a distraction. *Think*. You're right, in general it will take quadratic time to optimise a function of two variables. But look at your specific objective function. It can be separated as a sum `f(i, j) = g(i) + h(j)`. Assuming you can maximise g and h, it's obvious how to maximise f. Of course, you have an extra constraint `i <= j`, so you'll need to know a bit more than the maxima about g and h... Think what information would help you.

Comment: The easy way to see to the solution is that when `A[i]` and `A[j]` is used, they will have an effective value of `A[i]+i`, and `A[j]-j` respectively. So make two arrays of `[ A[i] + i, for all i ]`, and `[  A[j] - j, for all j ]`. Pick the max from both arrays and add them together.

Answer (score 6):

The crucial insight is that it can be done in O(n) only if you track where potentially useful values are even before you're certain they'll prove usable.

Start with best_i = best_j = max_i = 0.  The first two track the i and j values to use in the solution.  The next one will record the index with the highest contributing factor for i, i.e. where `A[i] - i` is highest.

Let's call the value of X for some values of i and j "X<sub>i,j</sub>", and start by recording our best solution so far ala X<sub>best</sub> = X<sub>0,0</sub>

Increment n along the array...

- whenever the value at `[n]` gives a better "i" contribution for `A[i] - i` than max_i, update max_i.
- whenever using `n` as the "j" index yields X<sub>max_i,n</sub> greater than X<sub>best</sub>, best_i = max_i, best_j = n.

### Discussion - why/how it works

j_random_hacker's comment suggests I sketch a proof, but honestly I've no idea where to start.  I'll try to explain as best I can - if someone else has a better explanation please chip in....

Restating the problem: greatest X<sub>i,j</sub> where j >= i.  Given we can set an initial X<sub>best</sub> of X<sub>0,0</sub>, the problem is knowing when to update it and to what.  As we contemplate successive indices in the array as potential values for j, we want to  generate X<sub>i,j=n</sub> for some i (discussed next) to compare with X<sub>best</sub>.  But, what i value to use?  Well, given any index from 0 to n is <= j, the j >= i constraint isn't relevant if we pick the best i value from the indices we've already visited.  We work out the best i value by separating the i-related contribution to X from the j-related contribution - `A[i] - i` - so in preparation for considering whether we've a new best solution with j=n we must maintain the best_i variable too as we go.

### A way to approach the problem

For whatever it's worth - when I was groping around for a solution, I wrote down on paper some imaginary i and j contributions that I could see covered the interesting cases... where Ci and Cj are the contributions related to n's use as i and j respectively, something like

```
n    0  1 2  3 4
Ci   4  2 8  3 1
Cj   12 4 3  5 9
```

You'll notice I didn't bother picking values where Ci could be A[i] - i while Cj was A[j] + j... I could see the emerging solution should work for any formulas, and that would have just made it harder to capture the interesting cases.  So - what's the interesting case?  When n = 2 the Ci value is higher than anything we've seen in earlier elements, but given only knowledge of those earlier elements we can't yet see a way to use it.  That scenario is the single "great" complication of the problem.  What's needed is a Cj value of at least 9 so Xbest is improved, which happens to come along when n = 4.  If we'd found an even better Ci at [3] then we'd of course want to use that.  best_i tracks where that waiting-on-a-good-enough-Cj value index is.

Comment: Ur solution makes me feel dumb to have been pondering otherwise.. :) Very nice.

Comment: That is exactly what I was thinking about when posting my comment. But had to think again if it could find wrong i > j... cannot, swapping those indexes would produce higher output, thus must be found by the search.

Comment: When does j get updated?  According to this algorithm, best_j will never change from its initial value of 0.

Comment: @j_random_hacker it does, on the second condition, best_j = j (although he mean "n" there) I tested his algorithm and it seems to work

Comment: @SeraphimFoA: Do you mean that all occurrences of "n" should be replaced with "j"?

Comment: @j_random_hacker I'll add the code on my answer to show you, it's difficult in the comment.

Comment: @j_random_hacker: I'd meant the second "whenever" to be contemplating n's suitability for use as a j value.  Hope SeraphimFoA's help and code clarified.  Cheers.

Comment: @TonyD: I see it now, thanks for the update.  Would be good to include a sketch of a proof of why it works.

Answer (score 2):

Longer version of my comment: what about iterating the array from both ends, trying to find the highest number, while decreasing it by the distance from the appripriate end. Would that find the correct indexes (and thus the correct X)?

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
#include <climits>

long long brutal(const std::vector<int>& a) {
    long long x = LLONG_MIN;
    for(int i=0; i < a.size(); i++)
        for(int j=i; j < a.size(); j++)
            x = std::max(x, (long long)a[i] + a[j] + j-i);
    return x;
}

long long smart(const std::vector<int>& a) {
    if(a.size() == 0) return LLONG_MIN;
    long long x = LLONG_MIN, y = x;
    for(int i = 0; i < a.size(); i++)
        x = std::max(x, (long long)a[i]-i);
    for(int j = 0; j < a.size(); j++)
        y = std::max(y, (long long)a[j]+j);
    return x + y;
}

int main() {
    std::random_device rd;
    std::uniform_int_distribution<int> rlen(0, 1000);
    std::uniform_int_distribution<int> rnum(INT_MIN,INT_MAX);
    std::vector<int> v;
    for(int loop = 0; loop < 10000; loop++) {
        v.resize(rlen(rd));
        for(int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++)
            v[i] = rnum(rd);
        if(brutal(v) != smart(v)) {
            std::cout << "bad" << std::endl;
            return -1;
        }
    }
    std::cout << "good" << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll write in pseudo code because I don't have much time, but this should be the most performing way using recursion

```
compare(array, left, right)

val = array[left] + array[right] + (right - left);

if (right - left) > 1
  val1 = compare(array, left, right-1);
  val2 = compare(array, left+1, right);

  val = Max(Max(val1,val2),val);
end if

return val
```

and than you call simply

```
compare(array,0,array.length);
```

I think I found a incredibly faster solution but you need to check it:

you need to rewrite your array as follow

```
Array[i] = array[i] + (MOD((array.lenght / 2) - i));
```

Then you just find the 2 highest value of the array and sum them, that should be your solution, almost O(n)

wait maybe I'm missing something... I have to check.

Ok you get the 2 highest value from this New Array, and save the positions i, and j. Then you need to calculate from the original array your result.

------------ EDIT

This should be an implementation of the method suggested by Tony D (in c#) that I tested.

```
        int best_i, best_j, max_i, currentMax;

        best_i = 0;
        best_j = 0;
        max_i = 0;
        currentMax = 0;

        for (int n = 0; n < array.Count; n++)
        {
            if (array[n] - n > array[max_i] - max_i) max_i = n;

            if (array[n] + array[max_i] - (n - max_i) > currentMax)
            {
                best_i = max_i;
                best_j = n;
                currentMax = array[n] + array[max_i] - (n - max_i);
            }

        }

        return currentMax;
```

Comment: Recursion is likely to be a _slow_ way of doing this.

Comment: That's unlikely to make it any better.

Comment: @JackAidley tested, and as I thought, if you use four thread performance double, if you further increase the number of thread performance start dropping again (I was sure that at least 8 thread should have increase performances, that was surprising) a part from that my original algorithm is not efficient at all, since it checks multiple time the same couples. Increasing the array make the execution time explode

Comment: That your recursive method can be faster with a load of threads doesn't really dispute my point - using recursion is going to be a slow way of doing it. To show your method is faster you'd need to compare it to an iterative method.

Comment: "That's unlikely to make it any better" seemed to me a reference to the recursive performance under multi-thread. you should have said "It would increase performance but it wouldn't still be comparable to the iterative version". I will in any case test the new recursive version I made against the iterative version (not the O(n) one that would surely be faster. the O(n*log(n)) version). I'm curious about how much difference there is.

Comment: Tested and performances are 4 time worst on the recursive version when array size is bigger than 1000 (around 3 times worst from 100 to 1000, and pretty the same for smaller array). Would like to test for huge array to see if performance drop more, but I got overflowed.

Answer (score 0):

**Question:**

Given an int array A[], define X=A[i]+A[j]+(j-i), j>=i. Find max value of X?

**Answer O(n):**

lets rewrite the formula: X = A[i]-i  +  A[j]+j

we can track the highest A[i]-i we got and the highest A[j]+j we got. We loop over the array once and update both of our max values. After looping once we return the sum of A[i]-i + A[j]+j, which equals X.

We absolutely don't care about the j>=i constraint, because it is always true when we maximize both A[i]-i and A[j]+j

**Code:**

```
int solution(vector<int> &A){
    if(A.empty()) return -1;

    long long max_Ai_part =-2000000000;
    long long max_Aj_part =-2000000000;
    int size = A.size();

    for(int i=0;i<size;i++){
        if(max_Ai_part < A[i] - i)
            max_Ai_part = A[i] - i;
        if(max_Aj_part < A[j] + j)
            max_Ai_part = A[j] - j;
    }

    return max_Ai_part + max_Aj_part;
}
```

**Bonus:**

most people get confused with the j>=i constraint. If you have a feeling for numbers, you should be able to see that i should tend to be lower than j.

Assume we have our formula, it is maximized and i > j. (this is impossible, but lets check it out)
we define x1 := j-i and x2 = i-j

A[i]+A[j]+j-i = A[i]+A[j] + x1, x1 < 0

we could then swap i with j and end up with this:

A[j]+A[i]+i-j = A[i]+A[j] + x2, x2 > 0

it is basically the same formula, but now because i > j the second formula will be greater than the first. In other words we could increase the maximum by swapping i and j which can't be true if we already had the maximum.
If we ever find a maximum, i cannot be greater than j.